# Python import pyDrive library error

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-client, pydrive

I installed the google API, pyDrive, and httplib2. I also got a token for my app in google and saved the `client_secret.json` file in my project's folder. I'm trying to simply run the following

```
print(sys.path)

from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth

gauth = GoogleAuth()

gauth.LocalWebserverAuth() # Creates local webserver and auto handles     authentication
```

but it throws a syntax error `invalid syntax (auth.py, line 160)` in the line

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
```

I can authenticate the app using the google drive API (without pydrive) but I'm unable to use pyDrive because of the described error, I've tried to append the following lines at the beginning of the script:

```
import sys
if "C:\\Users\\giovanni.sumano\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\pydrive" not in sys.path:
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\giovanni.sumano\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\pydrive")
```

because `C:\\Users\\giovanni.sumano\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\pydrive` is the only path where I've found pydrive libraries, additionally I've tried to add the path to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable via cmd, neither has worked for me so far. Does anybody know how can I make pyDrive work for me?

I'm running python on windows 8.1 and visual studio and python tools for visual studio.

Comment: If `from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth` is line 160 of `auth.py`, the `invalid syntax` error occurs somewhere **before** this line. I suggest commenting out the preceding lines of code one at a time to determine which line actually contains the syntax error.

Comment: Are you running this in 2.x? If so, the error is with that print call.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response @dim. Even If I delete everything before `from pyDrive.auth import GoogleAuth` I still get the error, I haven't been able to use dyDrive.

Comment: Just in case, do you have any package named **pydrive** or **auth.py** on your project? Sometimes I create .py files with the same name of the package and I have problems

Comment: @GiovanniFrancisSumanoArias the secrets file should be named `client_secrets.json` (note the 's'). If you are still experiencing this bug you can open an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/googledrive/PyDrive).